# Не работает модульная структура в jquery

Tags: jquery

Не работает

```js
(function($) {
  'use strict';
  sum: () => alert('Простой текст');
})(jQuery);

$(function() {
  'use strict';
  $('#btn').click(() => $.sum());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Кнопка">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это же не объект а тело функции, следующая запись - некорректна, да и к аргументу `$` Вы никак не обращаетесь:

```
(function($) {
   sum: () => alert('Простой текст');
})(jQuery);
```

Нужно обратиться к объекту через точку и присвоить значение через равно:

```js
(function($) {
  'use strict';
  $.sum = () => alert('Простой текст');
})(jQuery);

$(function() {
  'use strict';
  $('#btn').click(() => $.sum());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Кнопка">
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
let foo = {
  'sum': (x, y) => {
    alert(x + y);
  }
};

$('input:button').click( () => {
    foo.sum(parseInt($('#txtl').val()), parseInt($('#txt2').val()));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txtl">
<input type="text" id="txt2">
<input type="button" id="btnl" value="Получить сумму чисел">
```

Comment: вы видите что написано? 
@KirillKorushkin вам говорит что-то такая конструкция:
    `(function($) {})(jQuery);`
Мне не нужны глобальные переменные, так я и сам могу.

Comment: Во-первых, негоже на ходу менять тело вопроса, особенно после того, как были предложены ответы. Этим вы обесцениваете решения. Во-вторых, Ваш вопрос в своей первой редакции сводился к вызову функции в теле определённого события. В-третьих, то, что Вы сейчас написали в вопросе не будет работать Никогда. Пожалуйста, почитайте про стрелочные функции: https://habr.com/ru/company/ruvds/blog/428566/ да и вообще про js/jquery. С уважением.

Answer (score 0):

`onclick` не является функцией jQuery. Замени `on` на `click`

Comment: заменил, не работает. Пример выше.

Comment: @spoon100500 вы все нужные библиотеки подключили?

Comment: что значит ВСЕ? Вы разве не видите?

Comment: @spoon100500 попробуй заменить функцию на `jQuery(document).ready(function($) { });`